# Multiple Threads Sharing One Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, sockets

I have a scenario where multiple threads need to communicate with external system on one socket. Each thread's message can be identified by a unique id.
In this scenario where all threads share same socket, can I use blockQueues. Since the threads can produce request and consume response, can i have singleton component say "Socketer" who holds the socket and have two BlockQueues (incoming & outgoing). Any message on outgoing queue is written on socket and any message from socket is sent to incoming queue. The socketer also maintains the hashtable of all the producer threads and as it reads response, it identifies the corresponding producer and hands over response to it.s

Please suggest if it is a right design approach or advise the improvement. My threads are actually WebServices and I am in Spring environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need the hash table, but you do need a response queue per thread. You could embed the correct response queue into the request message.

But are you sure you can't open multiple connections to the external system? It would make your life a lot simpler.

Comment: Communicating on only one socket is requirement. The request message is a simple binary sequence sent over TCP. Since there is only one component who reads/writes on socket. It needs to have reference to producer/ message sender thread so that it can handover the response to correct thread. That's why I am thinking to have hastable which will store reference to all the threads who have sent request and waiting for response.

Comment: And then what? You're going to have to write the response to a queue per thread eventually. The Hashtable if it exists should map source threads to their consumer queues. It might be simpler just to synchronize on the socket and avoid the extra thread and all the queues, unless the extra service is capable of pipelining.

Comment: There is no 'consumer' queues. All the communication is on single socket.

Comment: Each thread will need a consumer queue so it can get its response back.

Comment: consumer queue per thread is good idea, thanks. If I synchronize on socket that means all threads will be waiting until T1(which holds socket lock) has finished writing request and have read response. In comparison to this approach, how about, threads come in, write request and go in waiting(hashtable). There is another thread who is monitoring the socket inputStream. As response comes in, its corresponding thread is looked up and response is handed over to it. Please suggest

Comment: If the external server doesn't do request pipelining they will all be waiting anyway. That also means that your idea of a second reading thread is just yet another pointless complication.

Comment: EJP can you please elaborate you last comment. The external system might work in asynchronous way i.e. response of R2 can come before R1 where R1 was sent earlier than R2

Comment: So it can pipeline, so you do need all the queues, and the second thread that reads the socket.